# Standard value of output that changes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 1 input. What i want to do is input = "5" then put "3" at "total" and "4" at "total2". And for every +1 to the input do +1 for "total" and "total2". 
Anything below 5 doesnt matter because my div with the output wont show if it is lower than 5.

So in short: "when I give an input of 5 I get an output of 4&5 but I need 3&4. And every +1 after that to the input I need a +1 to the outputs."

This is what i have so far:

```js
function updateTotal() {
  var total = 0; //
  var total2 = 0; //
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    values.push(parseFloat(list[i].value));
  }
  total = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  });
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
  document.getElementById("total2").value = total - 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input name="total" type="text" id="total" value="">
<input name="total2" type="text" id="total2" value="">
```

But i cant seem to figure out how to give it a standard value of 3 and 4.

Comment: What are "outputplace1" and "outputplace2"? They are nowhere in the code you have posted. Are those the "total" and "total2"?

Comment: Yes @mhodges :D.

Comment: I made a running snippet which helps people run your code. You can do that with the `<>` icon in the editor.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase exactly what you are trying to accomplish? The way the question is currently worded, I cannot figure out what you want your output to look like for any given input

Comment: _"input = "5" then..._ — you state what happens for inputs greater than 5, but what happens if input is _less than_ 5?

Comment: With the presamble button? i dont see any <> in the editor. so i dont really know how to do it. @markmeyer

Comment: you have `value=""` in your inputs. It's responsible for the standard value. So you need `<input name="total" type="text" id="total" value="3">`
`<input name="total2" type="text" id="total2" value="4">`

Comment: I updated my question. sorry guys&girls

Comment: But then when i give an input of 5 i get an output of 4&5 but i need 3&4. And every +1 after that to the input i need a +1 to the outputs. @smollet777

Comment: Why do you create `values` array and then reduce it to single value? Wouldn't it be better to sum up the numbers in the `for loop` right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get how those `for-loop` and `reduce` relevant to the problem with only one `<input class='input'>` but ok...

*What i want to do is input = "5" then put "3" at "total" and "4" at "total2".*

In another words you need your two inputs to be -1 and -2 of the value of that first input.

```js
function updateTotal() {
  // var total = 0; I don't know
  // var total2 = 0; why you wrote those

  // I assume you have multiple <input class="input"> 
  const list = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    values.push(parseFloat(list[i].value));
  }
  //and here you accumulate all those values
  let total = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  });


  // but code relevant to the problem is DOWN HERE

  // here you assigned INPUT value to TOTAL (eg input==5)
  // document.getElementById("total").value = total; but you need 2 less
  document.getElementById("total").value = total - 2;

  // here you assigned INPUT-1 value to TOTAL (eg input=4)
  // all ok here
  document.getElementById("total2").value = total - 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();' placeholder="input">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input name="total" type="text" id="total" placeholder="total">
<input name="total2" type="text" id="total2" placeholder="total 2">
```